# WinForm in VS2022 ListView height problem in runtime

Tags: winforms, listview, visual-studio-2022

Hi VS2022 programmers,

I have made a UserControl which is compiled as a dll and used as a Plugin for AutoCAD

There is something I can't figure out when ListView is rendered in WinForms.
I have put a ListView on a TabPage in a Tabcontrol. It is anchored to all sides.

In design time I can resize and the listview acts as supposed (expand and shrink)

But in runtime the height is not calculated correct as seen on screen captures.

It extends out of the TabPage/TabControl and when inserting rows to the ListView at runtime I cannot scroll to the rows that is outside the TabPage.

I have tried to put the ListView in a Panel a TableLAyoutPanel with the same result.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Dock the `ListView` to fill the `TabPage`. Select the LV, switch to the properties window, and set the `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill`.

Comment: Is the ListView child of the first TabPage (visible when the TabControl is first created)? -- Try first to make the UC scale to DPI instead of the default Font